# Remove Wordpress title from parent theme

Tags: php, wordpress

this is a bit of a rehash of a previous question I asked, but I now I have a clearer idea of what I'm asking...

I have the following code, which is in my parent theme and generates the  tag for my site... this is located in the directory: themes/kalium/inc/laborator_filters.php

```
// Title Parts
function kalium_wp_title_parts( $title, $sep, $seplocation ) {
    $kalium_separator = apply_filters( 'kalium_wp_title_separator', ' &ndash; ' );

    if ( empty( $sep ) ) {
        return $title;
    }

    $title_sep = explode( $sep, $title );

    if ( ! is_array( $title_sep ) ) {
        return $title;
    }

    if ( $seplocation == 'right' ) {
        $title = str_replace( $sep . end( $title_sep ), $kalium_separator . end( $title_sep ), $title );
    } else {
        $title = str_replace( reset( $title_sep ) . $sep, reset( $title_sep ) . $kalium_separator, $title );
    }

    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'wp_title', 'kalium_wp_title_parts', 10, 3 );
```

So, I'm trying to disable this from my child theme functions.php file using the following code with no success:

```
remove_filter( 'wp_title', 'kalium_wp_title_parts', 10, 3 );
```

I also tried adding it inside its own function like so:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_head_title', 0 );

    function remove_head_title() {

        remove_filter( 'wp_title', 'kalium_wp_title_parts', 10, 3 );
    }
```

Still with no success.

I have also tried to just copy the original code into my functions file so I could make alterations, but it didn't work.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Getting rid of it completely would be ideal but i would also be happy to just copy it into my child theme so I can alter it?

--------- UPDATE ----------

Ive just updated my code the the following:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_head_title', 0 );

    //change page title
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'change_page_title', 1000 );

function change_page_title($title)
{
   $title = 'wrgergdg'; // set new title here 
   // $title = ''; // or set title to an empty string
   return $title;
}
```

But still doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: Not experienced in Wordpress, but removing filter wont have any effect from what I understand: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/ . Do you want to remove it from your html-template?

Comment: The situation is, I have added custom fields for SEO page titles and page descriptions so I can have greater control of them without installing a heavy plugin like Yoast SEO - But now I have done that, I seems to have two page titles showing on my site. So, I wanted to remove the main one Wordpress automatically creates and just leave behind my custom <title> - The theme I'm using generates the Wordpress title tag from the above code and I'm trying to disable it - I can just delete it, bu then when the theme updates, i will overwrite my changes. Hence trying to remove it inside my child theme.

Answer (score 1):

remove_filter accepts three arguments

```
remove_filter( $tag, $function_to_remove, $priority );
```

remove last argument from your code.

**Update**

```
//change page title
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'change_page_title', 1000 );

function change_page_title($title)
{
   $title = 'new title'; // set new title here 
   // $title = ''; // or set title to an empty string
   return $title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can remove the 3 from my code (and the comma) but it seems to now work. I have just tried removing that chunk of code from the  parent file and nothing seems to happen so now I'm even doubting if the location of the code I was given by the theme builders is even correct...

Comment: Would you happen to know how I could copy the whole function into my child function file and just make changes to it? Currently if I do that it stops the site from working, I think I need to remove the function with the code above and then add it again?

Comment: Copy your code to child theme and rename your function (to prevent function name conflict) and add high priority to your add_filter.

Comment: Thank you - I have it in the child functions file now and its working wit a conflict, I just have to figure out which parts I can edit... I essentially want to just delete the whole <title> tag - But I have tried removing the whole piece of code and it doesn't seem to alter it for some reason

Comment: you can not delete the whole title tag. But you can set an empty value for title tag. Use `return ''` instead of `return $title` in your child theme and remove other lines from your function.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm trying this: 

// Title Parts
function kalium_wp_title_parts_new( $title, $sep, $seplocation ) {

 return ' '
}

add_filter( 'wp_title', 'kalium_wp_title_parts_new', 15, 3 );

but nothing? I'm not sure which part of the function I'm supposed to remove?

Comment: Thanks again! :) But Im still not sure where it goes - I've updated my original question with the code I'm trying that includes your code? this is obviously wrong. I'm sorry to keep asking, Once I see the right answer ill be able to deconstruct it and learn from it, but I'm struggling to apply your code in the correct place...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Ive found this code to work perfectly... Thanks everybody for your help and patience :)

```
// Remove title tag
function custom_remove_title_tag() {
    remove_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_remove_title_tag', 10000 );
```